# Why are the optional query parameters appearing in child action when using Html.Action inside of a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In an MVC application I have 2 action methods. One displays part of layout and in the middle of it, it tries to render the other action (which renders a list of items). For convenience sake I made it so, that if I ajax the first action I will get the result of the second one instead.

The code looks something like this:

```
public ActionResult Action1(int? foo = null, int? bar = null, string search = null)
{
    ViewBag.Foo = foo;
    ViewBag.Bar = bar;
    ViewBag.Bar = search;
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest() || this.ControllerContext.IsChildAction)
    {
        return Action2(foo, bar, search);
    }
    var model = GetSomeData();
    return View(model);
}

public ActionResult Action2(int? foo = null, int? bar = null, string search = null)
{
    ViewBag.Foo = foo;
    ViewBag.Bar = bar;
    ViewBag.Bar = search;
    var model = GetSomeOtherData(foo, bar, search);
    return View();
}
```

Then in **View** for Action1:

```
@model SomeClass
<div>
    Some layout and stuff from the model goes here
    @Html.Action("Action2", new { foo = ViewBag.Foo, bar = ViewBag.Bar })
</div>
```

And **View** for Action2:

```
@model IEnumerable<SomeOtherClass>
<div>
    <form action="@Url.Action("Action1", new { foo = ViewBag.Foo, bar = ViewBag.Bar })">
        <input type="text" name="search"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>
    Here we render a list of items from the model
</div>
```

When both `foo` and `bar` are null and I ajax Action1 or just request Action2, the URL in the form will not include the query parameters that are null. The problem appears when I request Action1 normally (not through ajax). Even though both `foo` and `bar` are null, the URL contain a query: `?foo=&bar=`.

Does anybody know **why** does this happen and\or **how to prevent it from happening? I mean I don't want to add query parameters if they are null.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andreiyfrag's answer gave me an idea on how to solve my problem. In the view for Action2 I just construct my routevaouedictionary manually like this:

```
var searchArguments = new Dictionary<string, object>();
if (ViewBag.Foo != null)
{
    searchArguments.Add("foo", ViewBag.Foo);
}
if (ViewBag.Bar != null)
{
    searchArguments.Add("bar", ViewBag.Bar);
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
@Url.Action("Action1", new RouteValueDictionary(searchArguments) )
```

It appears that if I construct an url in a view of a child action (`Url.Action`), all the provided query parameters will be included (even if they are null), but if the same action was run as a normal one (non-child action), then null parameters would have been omitted. I have no idea why does this happen, could it be that it's a bug in Razor or MVC?

Answer (score 1):

Well why don't you check if they are null in View ? and if they are just use:

```
@{
var foo = ViewBag.Foo;
var bar = ViewBag.Bar;
}

@if(foo == null && bar == null){

@Html.Action("Action2","ControllerName")
}
```

Comment: Your answer gave me an idea on how to solve my problem. Rather than making a set of ifs for all the combinations of foo and bar, I just construct the routevaluedictionary manually.